# How do I design SpringBoot Pagination Restful API with Kafka topic?

Tags: api, apache-kafka

I am trying to build a pagination restful API that fetches data from the Kafka topic.

For example, inside my Kafka topics, I have 1 billion messages whose data structure is like the following:

```java
class Record {
   String ID;
   JsonObject studentInfo;   
}
```

How do I get the paginated query result for a specific student id? For example, I want to get 200 records of the student whose id is `0123` and this student might or might not have 200 records on the Kafka topic.

My intuitive approach was to poll data from the Kafka topic, keep the offset on the topic and keep reading the data on the Kafka topic until I have 200 specific student records or reach the end of the Kafka topic. However, I am not sure if this is the right approach I should take.

Comment: This is NOT the use case for kafka. Kafka is a pub/sub not a data store. You might end up reading all 1billion messages in kafka to serve every request.

Comment: @RishabhSharma Thanks for replying to my question. From docs I've read, I know it might not be the use case. How about this: I have a Kafka topic that has 1 billion messages on it and I need to design a restful pagination API service, what's the appropriate way to design it?

Comment: You can dump this data into some data warehouse and query on it for whatever API logic needed. If you don't have a data warehouse setup - you can even dump data on s3 in structured format like delta tables and query it later. Refer to https://docs.databricks.com/delta/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The Confluent REST Proxy already does what you want, so I would recommend using that, rather than reinventing the wheel

```
GET /consumers/(string:group_name)/instances/(string:instance)/records
```

> Fetch data for the topics or partitions specified using one of the subscribe/assign APIs

Where, rather than number of records to poll, you give it a timeout (e.g. `consumer.poll(Duration timeout)`), or `max_bytes` (consumer config `fetch.max.bytes`, I think).

Re-GET that API endpoint to get the next "batch" (i.e. page) of records

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html

> for a specific student id?

You wouldn't. That's not how Kafka works. If this is a feature you really need, then you can use [Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/33/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) feature from Kafka Streams, which [Spring has an `InteractiveQueryService` class that can help with this](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/09/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-6-state-stores-and-interactive-queries).

Or, as mentioned in the comments, dump your topic to a database, indexed by ID, then build an API endpoint that will query and paginate from that.